# How to merge and observe two collections in Firestore based on reference ID in documents?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable, rxfire

I'm creating a `StencilJS` app (no framework) with a Google Firestore backend, and I want to use the `RxFire` and `RxJS` libraries as much as possible to simplify data access code. How can I combine into a single observable stream data coming from two different collections that use a reference ID?

There are several examples online that I've read through and tried, each one using a different combination of operators with a different level of nested complexity. https://www.learnrxjs.io/ seems like a good resource, but it does not provide line-of-business examples that make sense to me. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174075/firestore-how-to-get-the-collection-value-from-another-collection-document-id-is) is very similar, and maybe the only difference is some translation into using RxFire? Still looking at that. Just for comparison, in SQL this would be a `SELECT` statement with an `INNER JOIN` on the reference ID.

Specifically, I have a collection for `Games`:

```
{ id: "abc000001", name: "Billiards" },
{ id: "abc000002", name: "Croquet" },
...
```

and a collection for `Game Sessions`:

```
{ id: "xyz000001", userId: "usr000001", gameId: "abc000001", duration: 30 },
{ id: "xyz000002", userId: "usr000001", gameId: "abc000001", duration: 45 },
{ id: "xyz000003", userId: "usr000001", gameId: "abc000002", duration: 55 },
...
```

And I want to observe a merged collection of `Game Sessions` where `gameId` is essentially replace with `Game.name`.

I current have a `game-sessions-service.ts` with a function to get sessions for a particular user:

```
import { collectionData } from 'rxfire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { GameSession } from '../interfaces';

observeUserGameSesssions(userId: string): Observable<GameSession[]> {

    let collectionRef = this.db.collection('game-sessions');
    let query = collectionRef.where('userId', '==', userId);

    return collectionData(query, 'id);
}
```

And I've tried variations of things with `pipe` and `mergeMap`, but I don't understand how to make them all fit together properly. I would like to establish an interface `GameSessionView` to represent the merged data:

```
export interface GameSessionView {
    id: string,
    userId: string,
    gameName: string,
    duration: number
}
```

```
observeUserGameSessionViews(userId: string): Observable<GameSessionView> {

    this.observeUserGameSessions(userId)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(sessions => {
            // What do I do here? Iterate over sessions 
            // and embed other observables for each document?
        }
    )
}
```

Possibly, I'm just stuck in a normalized way of thinking, so I'm open to suggestions on better ways to manage the data. I just don't want too much duplication to keep synchronized.

Comment: you can array functions to do that instead of rxjs

Comment: @FanCheung I'm not sure what that means, "array functions." Isn't that essentially what `pipe(...)` does? I'm just not sure what - or how - to chain things together. RxJS has so many building blocks, and I'm fairly new to JavaScript as it is.

Comment: I've gone through my data model and denormalized quite a bit just to work around this issue. I understand normalization isn't necessarily the way to go in a NoSql setup, but it would be good to know if this sort of "join" can be done client-side with RxJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code (also available as [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4ycats)):

```
const games: Game[] = [...];
const gameSessions: GameSession[] = [...];

combineLatest(
  of(games),
  of(gameSessions)
).pipe(
  switchMap(results => {
    const [gamesRes, gameSessionsRes] = results;
    const gameSessionViews: GameSessionView[] = gameSessionsRes.map(gameSession => ({
      id: gameSession.id,
      userId: gameSession.userId,
      gameName: gamesRes.find(game => game.id === gameSession.gameId).name,
      duration: gameSession.duration
    }));
    return of(gameSessionViews);
  })
).subscribe(mergedData => console.log(mergedData));
```

**Explanation:**
With `combineLatest` you can combine the latest values from a number of Obervables. It can be used if you have ["multiple (..) observables that rely on eachother for some calculation or determination"](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html).
So assuming you lists of `Game`s and `GameSession`s are Observables, you can combine the values of each list.
Within the `switchMap` you create new objects of type `GameSessionView` by iterating over your `GameSession`s, use the attributes `id`, `userId` and `duration` and find the value for `gameName` within the second list of `Game`s by `gameId`. Mind that there is no error handling in this example.
As `switchMap` expects that you return another Observable, the merged list will be returned with `of(gameSessionViews)`.
Finally, you can `subscribe` to this process and see the expected result.

For sure this is not the only way you can do it, but I find it the simplest one.