# Add firestore collection value without document

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am new to firebase firestore And I can't add object directly into the collection see the image [wrong result](https://nimb.ws/d5DsZO)  and [expected result](https://nimb.ws/L7YjH9)

Tried

```
 admin.firestore()
        .collection('/user/DVCeb96fLKNAeVo1YIbukAOWMI12/balance/')
        .doc()
        .set(userBalance)
```

It creating a new document under balance collection but I need its Object value directly inside the balance collection

Comment: Use 'Realtime Database'

Comment: Check this link 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174075/firestore-how-to-get-the-collection-value-from-another-collection-document-id-is'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible in Firestore. The documentation specifies that the only possible structure is (for this case):

> Collection -> Document -> Doc Info

You will have to have some document under the collection, however, you also have the option of using the 'Realtime Database', which is a little different, but will allow this.

If you insist on using Firestore then I recommend setting a global constant (some String to describe the document name), and using that to access the info in the doc.