# How to join two collections in firebase with array of ids using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to firebase and I am trying to get data from firebase. In MySQL, this is very easy but I don't know how can we join collections in firebase. Please guide me to solve this small issue.

Below is the data in my firebase.

[image]

I want to get match the team ID with the users' collection. Below is my code with where condition but it is not working.

```
 getProjects() {
    this.firestore.collection('projects').valueChanges().subscribe(projects => {
      // console.log(projects)
      // this.projects = projects;
      const teamRef = this.firestore.collection('users');
      projects.forEach(project => {
        teamRef.where('')
      })
      // console.log(this.projects)
    })
  }
```

Any solution Appreciated!

Comment: You would have to first query the team document and then query each team member individually

Comment: @Dharmaraj can you please show with an example

Comment: Checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47335666/13130697) that has a similar use case.